# How can I bump my unsolved question?

Tags: support

Is there a "bump" feature to move an old unsolved/unanswered question to the top of the list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Editing your question bumps it to the top in the "Active" list (default for all visitors).

But just don't edit it to bump it, add more information, the results of your research, etc. so that it has a better chance of being answered. If you're not getting any answers at all you usually need to add more information.

Tips here:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask

You can also add a bounty:

- https://askubuntu.com/faq#bounty

Comment: But what if i am done with all details about the post ? there should be a step right ?

Comment: please add a link to the question you are asking to your question.

Comment: If you have nothing to add and have no answers, bounty it -- you have enough rep :)

Comment: yup that's cool answer :D , thank you amigos.