# How do I bump questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

How can I bump my question up to the front page so it will be seen without asking it again? I feel like once you ask a question, if it's not answered that day, it kind of goes into limbo.

Comment: This is really a Meta question, though a simple answer is that you can't and I believe it's frowned upon if you do bump it. The correct way to draw more attention to a question is to [bounty](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) it if you have rep to spare. See this Meta SO question: [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: Editing in more information raises it on the list, and it gives readers more detailed information on the problem, just don't try to game the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions about questions are what we call [meta-questions](http://meta.askubuntu.com/).

Your question was already [raised there](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3540/how-can-i-bump-my-unsolved-question). You have [the privilege](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) to parcitipate in  http://meta.askubuntu.com as soon as you've got 5 or more reputation.

Comment: Next time, just flag it for migration ;).

Comment: Flag, "Off Topic", "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" and the only option is meta-askubuntu.