# How does a newbie reply to their own post?

Tags: discussion, support

Long story short, I've submitted a few questions lately that have gone unanswered before disappearing off the front page into the void.

I understand that reputation is required before I can reply to my own post (to hopefully bump it back into existence), or offer any bounty for the question. However I'm *very* new to Ubuntu, and can't work out how I can earn reputation without offering solutions to others - something I'm technically incapable of doing.

What are my options here? Am I missing something?

Edit: So apparently, requiring 15 rep to answer doesn't mean it *costs* 15 rep to answer. ie., you keep the rep after you answer. That does make *a lot* more sense.

Comment: Edit other peoples posts, fix there spelling and grammer and add tags, each edit will get you 2 rep but make sure to do a good job because the community must review it. Also asking good questions is almost as good a way to get rep as answering them. as you say you are new, I am sure you have many questions.

Comment: You do not need reputation to post answers. You can't comment, but you can answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 [You cannot answer your own question if you have less than 15rep.](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Soundscape You're only 2 reps away from being able to answer your own posts. That's exactly 1 edit suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you have seen the chapter about reputation in the help center, but it explains well how you increase your points, so please review it one more time.

One of the ways to gain more reputation, is to get 200 points or more, on any of the Stack Exchance (SE) sites. If that happens, you get 100 extra points on each of the other SE sites, you're a member of.

For example, if you provide good answers on StackOverflow - about Python - or on the Mathematics and Physics sites, you have a chance to gain reputation on Ask Ubuntu, even if you've never posted an answer there.

So you may have more up your sleeve, than you realize. You don't have to stick to physical sciences. If you're good at languages, English, Spanish, whatever, there are language sites. If you like travelling, there is travel.stackexchange.com for you.

You can find all the SE sites by clicking [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#). You can use the same account as you're using for Ask Ubuntu, for any of the sites. I wish you good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You only [need 15 rep to be able to answer your own questions](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). You are 2 rep away from your goal. All you need is one edit suggestion that gets validated by reviewers in order to get them.

### BUT

You shouldn't answer questions just to bump them. Those answers will be reviewed and deleted. If you get too many posts deleted, your account would most likely get suspended.

Instead [edit your question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3540/how-can-i-bump-my-unsolved-question) by adding more information so they get bumped and so more people would be able to help.